# docker works but docker-compose failed

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm working with mysql docker image, this works:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345678 -d mysql:5.7.21
```

now I'd like to turn this into a docker-compose yml file:

```
version: "3"
services: 

  mysql:
   image: mysql:5.7.21
  environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:12345678
  container_name: some-mysql
```

when docker-compose up, it shows following error:

```
Recreating test-mysql
Attaching to some-mysql
some-mysql | error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified 
some-mysql |   You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,   MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

some-mysql exited with code 1

any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the `environment` block of `docker-compose.yaml` file.

According to the [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) documentation an `environment` block should be either:

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345678
```

or

```
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
```